# Insert DateTime into postgreSql database using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I'm trying to insert datetime field using VB.Net:

This is my code:

```
Command = New NpgsqlCommand("insert into test_base(create_date) values( '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff").ToString + "')", conn)
```

But it insert the date into 12 H format , I need to insert the date into 24 H format.

Comment: Please read about parameterized query. By the way if you store dates as strings you will have to face a lot of problems. Dates should be stored as Dates

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I need just to get the date into 24 Hours.

Comment: DateTime types are a *value* they dont have a format - formats are how dates are displayed to humans.  If the DB column is a Date Type, just pass a DateTime value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "hh" to "HH" as per below:

```
Command = New NpgsqlCommand("insert into test_base(create_date) values( '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff").ToString + "')", conn)
```

This link shows several ways you can manipulate the format:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use currentlty the pg function to_timestamp:

```
 Insert into foo(t) VALUES(to_Timestamp('17/05/15 14:38:55','dd/mm/yy HH24:mi:ss'))
```

No possibilities to error.
If you have to insert more rows, think about parametrized queries.